# Is it possible to conditionally assign a value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am looking to shorten this line of code.

```
const variableName = variableName === 0 ? 1 : variableName;
```

Is it possible to rewrite it with only one case of the variable name like so:

```
const variableName = variableName | 1?
```

Comment: That or a straight `if` are as nice as it gets unless `variableName` is falsey originally, in which case you can do `variableName = variableName || 1`. That isn't as generally applicable though, since it requires that the original value of `variableName` is falsey.

Comment: Do you really want to invert a boolean…? `foo = !foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, `const variableName = variableName | 1` is invalid because you can't redeclare `variableName` that has already been declared (and in strict mode you can't refer to it not knowing if it has or hasn't been declared in the current scope).

A pattern that turns up quite a lot is

```
function test(variableName) {
  variableName = variableName | 1;
  // do something with variableName
}
```

or alternatively

```
//not supported in IE, but might be useful if code is passed through a build step,
//or IE support is not important.
function default(variableName = 1) {
  // do something with variableName
}
```

or

```
function constVersion(variableName) {
  const constName = variableName | 1;
  //do something with constName
}
```

Just be aware of treating all 'false-y' values of `variableName` equivalently.

Answer (score 1):

```
const variableName = (variableName === 0 && 1) || variableName;
```

Comment: Seems that the goal was to *shorten* that line of code

Answer (score 1):

`|` is a binary OR operator
`||` is a logical OR operator

---

Also, you can't do

```
const variableName = variableName || 1;
```

```js
const variableName = 0;

const variableName = variableName || 1;
```

because you can't declare twice the same variable using `const`. It would more be :

```
const variableName = otherVariableName || 1;
```

I guess what you want to do is to avoid `variableName` to be ***initialized*** with 0 value (I guess you don't want `false` or `undefined` either).

---

---

```js
const otherVariableName = 0;

const variableName = otherVariableName || 1;

console.log(variableName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following syntax:

```
const variableName = variableName || 1
```

Keep in mind that this uses javascript's notion of falsey, so if variableName is 0, "", undefined, null or some other values this would evaluate to 1.